# Proof of reverse binary strings?

Tags: string, binary, proof, induction

If *w* : {1...L} → {0,1} is a binary string, the complement of *w*, denoted w<sup>C</sup>, is a string of length *L* defined by: w<sup>c</sup>(i) = 1 - w(i). The reverse of *w*, denoted w<sup>R</sup>, is the string of the length *L* defined by w<sup>R</sup>(i) = w(L + 1 - i). Use these definitions to give careful proof that, for every binary string x, (x<sup>C</sup>)<sup>R</sup> = (x<sup>R</sup>)<sup>C</sup>.

I have no idea how to start this question. I don't really want a direct answer I'd like to learn how to do this question by induction for future questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the solution I see is the simplest one, then it's a quite comprehensive exercise.

I suggest you start by proving a the following lemmas:

**Lemma 1**: (w0)<sup>C</sup>=(w<sup>C</sup>)1

**Lemma 2**: (w0)<sup>R</sup>=0(w<sup>R</sup>)

Both Lemma 1 and 2 can be proven by induction on the length of *w*. Doing it strictly by the given rules is tedious, but not very hard.

Argue that the following lemmas hold as well by the same argument

**Lemma 1b**: (w1)<sup>C</sup>=w<sup>C</sup>0

**Lemma 2b**: (w1)<sup>R</sup>=1(w<sup>R</sup>)

With those lemmas in place, you should be able to tackle the original problem of showing (x<sup>C</sup>)<sup>R</sup>=(x<sup>R</sup>)<sup>C</sup>.

Do an induction over *L* (i.e. the length of the word). The base case should be trivial. In the inductive step you'll end up with something like

Induction hypothesis

- (u<sup>C</sup>)<sup>R</sup>=(u<sup>R</sup>)<sup>C</sup>.

Left to show:

- ((u0)<sup>C</sup>)<sup>R</sup>=((u0)<sup>R</sup>)<sup>C</sup>

and (by analogy)

- ((u1)<sup>C</sup>)<sup>R</sup>=((u1)<sup>R</sup>)<sup>C</sup>

Solving this step will involve the lemmas above.